# Regular expression to check in a word for repeated letter and prevent input of character or symbol

Tags: java, regex

Am just trying to write a method in java that will use regular expression to check if a word does not contain any repeated letter whether "AAA" or "Aba" or "aa" and does not include any special characters like $, !, &, ....

Here is what I tried so far.

```
public boolean checkWord(String word) {
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9])\\1{1}");
        Matcher match = regex.matcher(word);
        if (match.find()) {
            return true;
        }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can imagine any regex solution to this having wickedly-bad backtracking problems. Do you have to use regex?

Comment: I thought so. but if there is any other possible method I would be open to use it.

Comment: Iterate character-by-character, recording that the current one has been seen if not seen before (e.g. by putting it into a set), and immediately returning if the current one has previously been seen before (e.g. if it is already in the set) or it is a "special character".

Comment: @Pshemo, the regex is checking for $ ! & only but can allow other special characters while it should only allow strings containing single letters or digits. e.g. Mine14

Comment: In that case just accept characters which are letters or digits. This seems to do what you want: `word.matches("(?i)(?:([a-z0-9])(?!.*\\1))+")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an alternate approach, here's a short method (in Java 9+) to do this without RegEx. It uses a set to keep track of characters it needs to reject.

Rather than checking if the character needs to be rejected using `set.contains()` then also `set.add()` later, I just call `set.add()` and use the result to catch if the character was already in the set. This way the set only needs to be searched once.

For each character in the word I convert it to lower case, try to add it to the set, if successful then continue with the next char, if unsuccessful then return true since this matches a string that needs to be rejected (you could negate this if needed).

```
/** Checks if a word contains any specified special characters, or any re-used character */
public static boolean checkWord(String word) {
    final Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('$', '!', '&'));
    return word.chars().anyMatch(i -> !set.add(Character.toLowerCase((char) i)));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = { "AAA", "Aba", "aa", "abc&def", "$omething", "exciting!", "abcd", };
    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.println(checkWord(word) + " : " + word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
public boolean checkWord(String word) {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]).*\\1|[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
    Matcher match = regex.matcher(word);
    return !match.find();
}
```

Please, notice that I basically switched your `true` and `false`.

Comment: @Samlz I edited my answer for making the method to "only allow strings containing single letters or digits".

Comment: You may want to add `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag to also handle cases like `Aba` (where `A` is repeated as `a`).

Answer (score -1):

It's still a bit unclear to me when you want the method to return true/false, but I think the main idea can be solved by the code below, without regex:

```java
    public boolean checkWord(String word) {
        final Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
        boolean passed = false;
        //using toLowerCase because `a` should be equal to `A`
        final char[] characters = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        for (char c : characters) {
            //if a special character is found, return false
            if (! Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
                return false;
            }
            
            //if caracter is in the set, it's a re-occurence
            if (set.contains(c)) {
                passed = true; //can't return, must check rest of string for special characters
            }
            //added to check re-occurrence
            set.add(c);
        }

        return passed;
    }
```

Comment: This is inaccurate according to what OP is asking for: `check if a word does not contain any repeated letter whether "AAA" or "Aba" or "aa" and does not include any special characters like $, !, &` Also it can be simplified quite a lot.